# docker compose: spring boot connection to mysql database refused

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I'm pretty new to Docker and I need to startup my Angular/SpringBoot/MySQL project with docker-compose on the docker toolbox. I copied a docker yml file into my project which used the same technologies and changed the paths inside of it to match my project. However when I try docker-compose, it throws the following error:

```
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
[...] 84 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

the docker-compose.yml looks like:

```
version: '3'

services:
  database:
    image: mysql
    container_name: database
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ****
      MYSQL_DATABASE: db_example
      MYSQL_USER: springuser
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ****
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    volumes:
      - db_exampleData:/var/lib/mysql

  springapi:
    image: openjdk:10-jre-slim
    container_name: springapi
    ports:
      - 8443:8443
    depends_on:
      - database
    volumes:
      - ./backend/target/backend-0.1.0.jar:/application.jar
    command: ["java", "-jar", "application.jar"]

  angular:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: angular
    ports:
      - 4200:80
    depends_on:
      - springapi
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./frontend/my-app/dist/my-app:/usr/share/nginx/html

volumes:
  db_exampleData:
```

the application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.open-in-view=false
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_example
spring.datasource.username=springuser
spring.datasource.password=****

server.port=8443
```

any suggestion would be helpful!

Comment: How is your application referencing to the MySQL container? How the URL looks like?

Comment: added the properties to the qeustion above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to change your connecion like this:

```
jdbc:mysql://database:3306/db_example
```

and add this to your docker-compose under `springapi` service:

```
links:
   - database
```

on the other hand you may use [wait-for-it.sh](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it/master/wait-for-it.sh) to check if DB is up by add a command section under `springapi` service:

```
command: ["path/to/wait-for-it.sh", "database:3306", "-t", "6000", "--", "YOUR ACTUAL COMMAND"]
```

Comment: thank you, that fixed the error. But somehow it stops building at "Tomcat started on port(s): 8443 (http) with context path ' ' ". Do you know what could be the issue here?

Comment: where should the wait-for-it.sh be placed? I put it in the same place where the yml file is too but it gives me an error (no such file or directory)

Comment: that was an optional , if you need to wait for the DB

Comment: yea I read that in a couple of other threads too so I think Im better off implementing it. I updated the last comment, accidently hit send while writing

Comment: this is the error it gives me right now: ERROR: for 6a693dd8da33_springapi  Cannot start service springapi: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"./wait-for-it.sh\": stat ./wait-for-it.sh: no such file or directory": unknown

Comment: yes sure , you need to get the script and install it first before you can use it- to do so you need to use `Dockerfile` . but as I said it is not a must

Comment: ok I'll look into that later. Right now docker just stops doing anything at 2019-06-25 13:26:39.553  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8443 (http) with context path '', it should print out a few more commands and the angular start